# Invisible ReCaptcha prompts image selection on every request

Tags: recaptcha

As the title says despite the fact that I am using ReCaptcha Enterprise invisible the image selection dialog pops up whenever `grecaptcha.execute()` method gets executed.

I have checked recaptcha admin and the Security Preferences is Easiest for users.

This is what the javascript code looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
            
                var timerFunction = function () {
                    // execute the grecaptcha function to generate a client token and set the hidden 
                    grecaptcha.enterprise.execute();
                    setTimeout(timerFunction, 60 * 1000);
                };
                window.grecaptcha.ready(function () {
                    // timer function which runs every minute to get a fresh recaptcha token
                    timerFunction();
                });
            })  
        </script>
```

So far, have checked the reCaptcha admin and Security preferences.